# Multiline replace with python regular expression

Tags: python, regex, multiline

I have a repeating text in a large file which I want to replace with some other text. For example:

some text.......\n
partition by range (STRT_DTTM)\n
some more text......\n
);
I want to use regex to find these blocks that start with partition by range and ends with ); and replace that block with 'THIS IS TEST'. I am using the below code 
import re

```
with open(r"C:\Users\x217838\Desktop\python\input.txt","rt") as in_file:
    text = in_file.read()
    s = re.compile("^partition by range(.*);\)$)",re.MULTILINE)
    replace = re.sub(s, 'THIS IS TEST', text)
    print(replace)
```

Can you please let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use \ for all regex reserved symbols --> `[\^$.|?*+(){}`. The final code will be:

```
import re
text = "partition by range(CANE) uno"
s = re.compile("^partition by range\(.*\)",re.MULTILINE)
replace = re.sub(s, 'THIS IS TEST', text)
print(replace)
```

The result is:

```
THIS IS TEST uno
```

Comment: That works, but I would have liked to have an explanation on why you escape the parentheses in your answer.

Comment: The reason is that '(' and ')' are reserved symbol, used internally by regex. if you want to use the actual char you have to use the escape

Comment: You have to use  \ for all this symbols -->  [\^$.|?*+(){}

Comment: I _know_. I meant _in the answer_. comments aren't made for that.

Comment: Can you show that with a multiline?  The block ends with );
use this text please

text = partition by range(CANE) uno 
         blah blah blah
         blah blahhh
        );

Answer (score 1):

If you have your text spanning across multiple lines something like this,

```
some text.......
partition by range (STRT_DTTM)
some more text......
);
```

Then you will have to use `(?s)` modifier to enable `.` matching a new line.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0iC37n/2)**

Sample python codes,

```
import re

s = '''some text.......
partition by range (STRT_DTTM)
some more text......
);'''

mods = re.sub(r'(?s)partition by range(.*?)\);','THIS IS TEST',s)
print(mods)
```

Prints,

```
some text.......
THIS IS TEST
```

Comment: Thank you !!! This is working but it is matching till the last ); Is there a way to match in non greedy way . Stop matching as soon as it finds the first pattern and replace it and start looking for the next pattern.

Comment: Sure, just change `.*` to `.*?` in the regex. Let me update my answer

Comment: I got it . THANK YOU VERYYY MUCH.